# IV generation/length is trashed by encoding

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, mcrypt

I am trying to use mcrypt to encryot/decrypt strings I pass by POST.
When I generate the IV, I get the right length (16), verified with `strlen`. 
`mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC), MCRYPT_RAND);`

I submit the IV inside a hidden input to a different page, on that page, when I do
`echo strlen($_POST['iv'])` I get numbers of 30 and above.
Although, the string looks the same as where It's length is 16.
Is it an encoding issue? How would I fix the IV (and presumably all my other encoded values) in the page where I encrypt those?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by encoding/decoding the values with `base64_*` on each respective page